# electronic device to manage power demand

Tags: power, ac

I want to start let's say 20 motors (110V, starting current 40A) for 5 seconds in the same time but my power supply can't handle more than 10 motors. There is any electronic device who can manage my power so I can run these 20 motors for 5 seconds in minimum amount of time: 10 seconds?

Thank you

Comment: Timing Relays and contactors or a PLC...

Comment: Two power supplies

Comment: While technically possible, connecting that many  motors to an unsuitable power distribution panel is a safety violation.   Upgrade the power distribution.   (in the US, "National Electric Code" is the reference for these requirements).

Answer (score 0):

I'd grab random Arduino and relay board along with additional power supply.

I'm assuming timing is not critical for your project, thus I'd go for I2c relay module, which you can use with Arduino or any other controller or board that supports i2c. i2c might be extended to control up to 1023 devices.

Arduino relay usage exmaple: [here](http://arduinobasics.blogspot.ru/2014/09/relay-module.html)

I2C relay module [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/I2C-Relay-Board/)

Comment: Thank you. Actually the time is the main problem.  The motors need to throw some switches in the shortest period of time.